# Where to find the goto statement in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I encountered this scenario that I just need to jump to another line of code in my program using AA. 
Unfortunately AA does not have ***`goto statement`***  in command section. Is there a **solution** on how to use ***`goto statement`*** in AA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutomationAnywhere doesn't have *"goto"* command.
Alternate options is you can create another task and use *Run Task* command.

If your requirement is like

```
loop(1..10)
{
if (num % 2 == 0)
    goto even;
else
    goto odd;
} 
even:    
    echo "even";
    return; 
odd:
    echo "odd";
    return;
```

You can design your AA Bot by creating 3 bots. MainBot, evenBot and oddBot.

MainBot should be like this.

```
loop(1..10)
{
if (num % 2 == 0)
    Run Task evenBot;
else
    Run Task oddBot;
}
```